# ActiveMerchant is not validating invalid credit cards

Tags: credit-card, activemerchant, validating

I have an issue with ActiveMerchant credit card validation in my rails 2.3.2 application.(ActiveMerchant 1.4.1)

I followed the railscast #145 episode codes exactly.

My problem is when I am validation the credit card with invalid data like :first_name,:last_name as empty, ActiveMerchant is not giving validations errors

I tried this in my script/console

```
credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(:number => "",:first_name => "")
credit_card.errors.full_messages #=> []
credit_card.errors #=> {}
```

My payment.rb contains

```
validate_on_create :validate_card

private

def validate_card
  unless credit_card.valid?
    credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
       errors.add_to_base message
    end
  end
end

def credit_card
  @credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
    :number             => card_number,
    :month              => card_expires_on.month,
    :year               => card_expires_on.year,
    :first_name         => first_name,
    :last_name          => last_name,
    :verification_value => cvv_number, 
    :type               => card_type
    )
 end
```

The credit card errors are not added to @payment object I created in my controller#create
Please tell me where I did mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add an an || in ur credit_card function

```
def credit_card
  @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
    :number             => card_number,
    :month              => card_expires_on.month,
    :year               => card_expires_on.year,
    :first_name         => first_name,
    :last_name          => last_name,
    :verification_value => cvv_number, 
    :type               => card_type
    )
 end
```